# how to display vertically overflowed items in inline block in css

Tags: javascript, html, css, inline

[index.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9Gqt.jpg)

I want to display the first five item in col 1 and the rest five item in col 2 using css or js any one of them.

Please help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a flex layout to set up columns.

```css
ol {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  height: 100px;
}

li {
  width: 150px;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
  <li>Item 7</li>
  <li>Item 8</li>
  <li>Item 9</li>
  <li>Item 10</li>
  <li>Item 11</li>
  <li>Item 12</li>
  <li>Item 13</li>
  <li>Item 14</li>
  <li>Item 15</li>
</ol>
```